# VSCode: TypeScript Extension in Settings

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

I have two Macs. My main one (Macbook Pro) has TypeScript settings but my other one (iMac) doesn't. I'v copied the settings so they are identical but it doesn't work. Anyone that knows how to fix this?

MacBook Pro:
[image]

and iMac:
[image]

and I have typescript installed:

```
~ tsc --version
Version 3.8.3
```

Comment: Did you disable the built-in JavaScript and TypeScript language features extension? In the extensions view, search `@builtin` to check

Comment: @MattBierner no, everything is Enabled there.